# Regarding Rudin's proof of Arzela-Ascoli

Tags: real-analysis

Recall Theorem 7.25 of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*:

> If $K$ is compact and $f_n \in \mathscr{C}(K)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and if $\{f_n\}$ is pointwise bounded and equicontinuous on $K$, then:
>
> (a) $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly bounded on $K$.
>
> (b) $\{f_n\}$ contains a uniformly convergent subsequence.

Here is the beginning of Rudin's proof of (a), suitably rewritten for my own intuition:

> Let $\epsilon > 0 $ and, by equicontinuity, pick $\delta > 0$ such that $d(x,y) < \delta \implies |f_n(x) - f_n(y)| < \epsilon$ for all $n$. Cover $K$ with $\delta$-balls, and find a finite subcover $P$ with centers $p_1, \dots, p_r$. $f_n$ is pointwise bounded, so $f_n(p_i) < M_i$ for all $n$. Let $M = \max\{M_1,\dots,M_r\}$. Then $|f(x)| < M + \epsilon$. (Note the importance of $\epsilon$, while $f(p_i) < M$, this is only for $p_i \in P$. We get the bound $M + \epsilon$ by equicontinuity, since all $x \in B(p_i, \delta)$ for some $i \in J_n$.

For the most part, this is clear, however, he chose to wrote $|f(x)| < M + \epsilon$ rather than $|f_n(x)| < M + \epsilon$. Is this simply abuse of notation, or am I missing something elementary?

Comment: Your implicit assumption that there are no typos in a big book is cute. (No comment on this particular situation.)

Comment: Thank you, working through Rudin makes you feel like you've lost your mathematical innocence.

Comment: I wouldn't know. I rarely found myself "working through" many things, none of the instances I did that were books, let alone intro level books, let alone intro to analysis.

Comment: It's a typo. It should be $f_n$.

Answer (score 3):

This is a typo that is fixed in newer versions of the 3rd edition. You are correct that it should read
$$
|f_n(x)|<M+\varepsilon.
$$